# RabbitMQ 2.7.1 doesn't start with configuration file; Reason: function_clause

Tags: rabbitmq

I try to use rabbit on ubuntu 12.04. After installation rabbitmq-server works fine. Than I stop it and add my configuration file.

```
root@rabbit1:~# tail /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf 
RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/myrabbitmq
root@rabbit1:~# tail /etc/rabbitmq/myrabbitmq.config 
[{rabbit,
    [{cluster_nodes, {['rabbit@rabbit1', 'rabbit@rabbit2'], disc}}]}].
```

With this files rabbitmq-server says on start:

```
root@rabbit1:~# rabbitmq-server
Activating RabbitMQ plugins ...
0 plugins activated:


+---+   +---+
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|   +---+   +-------+
|                   |
| RabbitMQ  +---+   |
|           |   |   |
|   v2.7.1  +---+   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
AMQP 0-9-1 / 0-9 / 0-8
Copyright (C) 2007-2011 VMware, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

node           : rabbit@rabbit1
app descriptor : /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-2.7.1/sbin/../ebin/rabbit.app
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/myrabbitmq.config
cookie hash    : 31CaH3BCSDNL1hDIFQzH2Q==
log            : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbit1.log
sasl log       : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbit1-sasl.log
database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@rabbit1
erlang version : 5.8.5

-- rabbit boot start
starting file handle cache server                                     ...done
starting worker pool                                                  ...done
starting database                                                     ...BOOT ERROR: FAILED
Reason: function_clause
Stacktrace: [{lists,usort,[{[rabbit@rabbit1,rabbit@rabbit2],disc}]},
             {rabbit_mnesia,init_db,3},
             {rabbit_mnesia,init,0},
             {rabbit,'-run_boot_step/1-lc$^1/1-1-',1},
             {rabbit,run_boot_step,1},
             {rabbit,'-start/2-lc$^0/1-0-',1},
             {rabbit,start,2},
             {application_master,start_it_old,4}]
Erlang has closed
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{rabbit,failure_during_boot}}}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{rabbit,failure_during_boot}}}}})
```

Have any suggestion what's wrong with my rabbit?

Comment: is there any reason why you are using such an old version? did you install it straight from apt?

Comment: no specific reason, just did `sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server`

Comment: bad idea read this http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html follow the instructions in the "our APT repository section". uninstall this version first.  I think you will have more luck with the new version.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow. This problem is in configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration file should be like this:

```
root@rabbit1:~# cat /etc/rabbitmq/myrabbitmq.config
[{rabbit,
  [{cluster_nodes, ['rabbit@rabbit1', 'rabbit@rabbit2'] }]}].
```

It seems, that disc or ram node configures in different way than in documentation to latest version of rabbit. In this configuration two disc nodes will be created. If somebody wants ram node this node should be ommitted in configuration of this node (not in other config files).